# Using fixture yields in helper functions with PyTest?

Tags: python, pytest

Title.

I have a, lets say,

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def anyio_backend():
    return "asyncio"
```

and

```py
@pytest.fixture
async def test_cards():
    yield "i am a card"
```

I want to use my fixture in a helper function, without passing the test_cards from test to helper like:

```py
async def my_helper_function(test_cards):
      print(test_cards)
@pytest.mark.anyio
async def some_test(test_cards):
      await my_helper_function(test_cards)
```

instead of the code above, I directly want:

```py
async def my_helper_function(test_cards):
      print(test_cards)
@pytest.mark.anyio
async def some_test():
       await my_helper_function() # see mom no hands
```

Is it possible without marking the helper function as a test like `@pytest.mark.anyio`?

Comment: There is a niche library https://github.com/saltstack/pytest-helpers-namespace that suffices my needs, but I do not want to use an unmaintained project and risk the entire project breaking down, just to trim four words from my code.